# ASP.NET VB Unable to loop through nested XML elements with Linq

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to read/list each `<lat>` and `<long>` point from the XML below.

The XML document is in a large file (approx 30,000 lines), here is a very cut down version:

```
Dim strMyXMLString As String = ""
strMyXMLString &= "<job>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "    <field>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "        <zones>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "            <zone>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                <zone_id>BEBB35C8</zone_id>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                <reference_id>1</reference_id>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                <point>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                    <lat>54.141774116</lat>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                    <lng>-0.754275931</lng>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                </point>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                <point>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                    <lat>54.141170056</lat>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                    <lng>-0.754093629</lng>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                </point>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                <point>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                    <lat>54.141169615</lat>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                    <lng>-0.754103682</lng>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                </point>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "            </zone>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "            <zone>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                <zone_id>F9A7ECBB</zone_id>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                <reference_id>2</reference_id>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                <point>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                    <lat>54.142055217</lat>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                    <lng>-0.752604533</lng>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                </point>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                <point>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                    <lat>54.141530045</lat>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                    <lng>-0.752207708</lng>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                </point>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                <point>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                    <lat>54.141528842</lat>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                    <lng>-0.752213287</lng>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "                </point>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "            </zone>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "        </zones>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "    </field>" & vbCrLf
strMyXMLString &= "</job>" & vbCrLf
```

There is only one `<zones>` element but there are many `<zone>` elements contained within.

In the example above I have also only listed three `<point>` co-ordinates per element, in the actual XML file there are approx 700 `<point>` values for each `<zone>` element.

I need to loop through each `<zone>` element and retrieve the `<zone_id>`, the `<reference_id>`, and each individual `<lat>` and `<lng>` contained within each `<zone>`.

The following code:

```
Dim strMyXMLDoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(strMyXMLString)
Dim zone = From point In strMyXMLDoc...<zones>.<zone> Select point

For Each item In zone
    ' Output some stuff
    Response.Write("<br>")
    Response.Write("<br>zone_id: " & item.<zone_id>.Value)
    Response.Write("<br>reference_id: " & item.<reference_id>.Value)

    ' This only lists the FIRST <lat> found and no more, which is technically right as we are still in the <zone> loop
    Response.Write("<br>first lat: " & item.<point>.<lat>.Value)
    Response.Write("<br>first lng: " & item.<point>.<lng>.Value)

    ' Getting desparate, try a nested loop
    Dim zone_point = From nested_points In strMyXMLDoc...<zones>.<zone>.<point> Select nested_points
    For Each zone_item In zone_point
        Response.Write("<br>lat: " & item.<point>.<lat>.Value)
        Response.Write("<br>lng: " & item.<point>.<lng>.Value)
    Next

Next
```

Produces the following output:

```
zone_id: BEBB35C8
reference_id: 1
first lat: 54.141774116
first lng: -0.754275931
lat: 54.141774116
lng: -0.754275931
lat: 54.141774116
lng: -0.754275931
lat: 54.141774116
lng: -0.754275931
lat: 54.141774116
lng: -0.754275931
lat: 54.141774116
lng: -0.754275931
lat: 54.141774116
lng: -0.754275931

zone_id: F9A7ECBB
reference_id: 2
first lat: 54.142055217
first lng: -0.752604533
lat: 54.142055217
lng: -0.752604533
lat: 54.142055217
lng: -0.752604533
lat: 54.142055217
lng: -0.752604533
lat: 54.142055217
lng: -0.752604533
lat: 54.142055217
lng: -0.752604533
lat: 54.142055217
lng: -0.752604533
```

And as you can see, it is repeating the first `<lat>` and `<lng>` six times.

I have tried this minor code change too:

```
Dim strMyXMLDoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(strMyXMLString)
Dim zone = From point In strMyXMLDoc...<zones>.<zone> Select point

For Each item In zone
    ' Output some stuff
    Response.Write("<br>")
    Response.Write("<br>zone_id: " & item.<zone_id>.Value)
    Response.Write("<br>reference_id: " & item.<reference_id>.Value)

    ' This only lists the FIRST <lat> found and no more, which is technically right as we are still in the <zone> loop
    Response.Write("<br>first lat: " & item.<point>.<lat>.Value)
    Response.Write("<br>first lng: " & item.<point>.<lng>.Value)

    ' Getting desparate, try a nested loop
    Dim zone_point = From nested_points In strMyXMLDoc...<zone>.<point> Select nested_points
    For Each zone_item In zone_point
        Response.Write("<br>lat: " & zone_item.<lat>.Value)
        Response.Write("<br>lng: " & zone_item.<lng>.Value)
    Next

Next
```

But that gives the following output (it is now listing ALL points it found, per `zone`):

```
zone_id: BEBB35C8
reference_id: 1
lat: 54.141774116
lng: -0.754275931
lat: 54.141170056
lng: -0.754093629
lat: 54.141169615
lng: -0.754103682
lat: 54.142055217
lng: -0.752604533
lat: 54.141530045
lng: -0.752207708
lat: 54.141528842
lng: -0.752213287

zone_id: F9A7ECBB
reference_id: 2
lat: 54.141774116
lng: -0.754275931
lat: 54.141170056
lng: -0.754093629
lat: 54.141169615
lng: -0.754103682
lat: 54.142055217
lng: -0.752604533
lat: 54.141530045
lng: -0.752207708
lat: 54.141528842
lng: -0.752213287
```

So we have blank values there, but again it has looped it six times (instead of three, right?)

My desired output needs to be:

```
zone_id: BEBB35C8
reference_id: 1
first lat: 54.141774116
first lng: -0.754275931
lat: 54.141774116
lng: -0.754275931
lat: 54.141170056
lng: -0.754093629
lat: 54.141169615
lng: -0.754103682

zone_id: F9A7ECBB
reference_id: 2
first lat: 54.142055217
first lng: -0.752604533
lat: 54.142055217
lng: -0.752604533
lat: 54.141530045
lng: -0.752207708
lat: 54.141528842
lng: -0.752213287
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

This code block:

```
Dim strMyXMLDoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(strMyXMLString)

Dim zone = From point In strMyXMLDoc...<zones>.<zone> Select point

For Each item In zone
    ' Output some stuff
    Response.Write("<br>")
    Response.Write("<br>zone_id: " & item.<zone_id>.Value)
    Response.Write("<br>reference_id: " & item.<reference_id>.Value)

    ' Nested loop
    Dim nested_point = item.<point>
    For Each zone_point In nested_point
        Response.Write("<br>lat: " & zone_point.<lat>.Value)
        Response.Write("<br>lng: " & zone_point.<lng>.Value)
    Next

Next
```

Provides an output of:

```
zone_id: BEBB35C8
reference_id: 1
lat: 54.141774116
lng: -0.754275931
lat: 54.141170056
lng: -0.754093629
lat: 54.141169615
lng: -0.754103682

zone_id: F9A7ECBB
reference_id: 2
lat: 54.142055217
lng: -0.752604533
lat: 54.141530045
lng: -0.752207708
lat: 54.141528842
lng: -0.752213287
```

The ***key*** line being:

```
Dim nested_point = item.<point>
```